PostgreSQL Nested Query Format
I am trying to create an SQL query to get one table data from a table based upon a cell value from a separate table.
My final query should look like this:
SELECT "NAME" FROM "CONTACT-BUSINESS" WHERE "ID" IN ('238120','238121') AND "ACTIVEFLAG" = 'Y'; -- this works

To make it execute properly I need to get the ('238120','238121') value from a second table:
SELECT '('||"ID_CONTRACTOR_CONTACT"||')' FROM "INPUT" WHERE "FK_SOURCE" = '20231725175' AND "DOCKET" = '324771' AND "ACTIVEFLAG" != 'N'; -- this works as well

I tried to nest them and this, & for me, this is where the problem is.  My current version of the SQL looks like this:
SELECT "NAME" FROM "CONTACT-BUSINESS" WHERE "ID" IN (SELECT '('||"ID_CONTRACTOR_CONTACT"||')' FROM "INPUT" WHERE "FK_SOURCE" = '20231725175' AND "DOCKET" = '324771' AND "ACTIVEFLAG" != 'N') AND "ACTIVEFLAG" = 'Y';

This returns no records, and I do not receive any errors.
If it helps I am running
pgAdmin 4 v 8.5


You need to remove the unnecessary string concatenation and parentheses in the subquery around ID_CONTRACTOR_CONTACT.
SELECT "NAME"
FROM "CONTACT-BUSINESS"
WHERE "ID" IN (
    SELECT "ID_CONTRACTOR_CONTACT"
    FROM "INPUT"
    WHERE "FK_SOURCE" = '20231725175'
    AND "DOCKET" = '324771'
    AND "ACTIVEFLAG" != 'N'
)
AND "ACTIVEFLAG" = 'Y';

